# Using Same If Else Statement Multiple Times

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm doing this...

```
<?php $term = ucfirst($_GET['term']);?>
```

And doing this multiple times on the page:

```
<?php if (empty($term)) echo 'X'; else echo $term; ?>
```

Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: I do not see any if-else-statements or structures in your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the placeholder value when you first assign the value:

```
<?php  $term = ucfirst($_GET['term'])  or  $term = "X";  ?>
```

(Works because the OR has lower precedence than the assignment.)

Then just print that variable henceforth:

```
<?= $term ?>
```

It will contain either the input value, or your `X`.

Comment: I would replace `$term = "X"` with `$term = 'X'` so it would get parsed faster ;-)

Comment: Looks like a few different solutions posted. This one worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

ternary operator :

```
$term = (empty(ucfirst($_GET['term']))) ? echo 'X' : $_GET['term'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a function

```
function doTerm()
{
    $term = ucfirst($_GET['term']);
    if (empty($term)) echo 'X'; else echo $term;
}
```

so you can call it like

```
doTerm();
```

whenever you need it to test and echo.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$term = isset($_GET['term']) ? ucfirst($_GET['term']) : 'X';
echo $term;

//...
?>
```

If you don't need it anywhere else than you could make it even shorter :-)

```
    echo (isset($_GET['term']) ? ucfirst($_GET['term']) : 'X');
```

Answer (score 0):

Ternary syntax can work easily here:

Using short hand tags:

```
<?=empty($term) ? 'X' : $term ?>
```

or long hand:

```
<?php echo empty($term) ? 'X' : $term ?>
```

Comment: you are using your codes in short open tag, even not sure the short open tags enables or not??

Comment: one day we can live in a world where we don't have to worry about short tags enabled. Making change now... :/

Answer (score 0):

you can use Conditional Operator like
echo ($term!=null)? 'x' : $term;

Comment: ternary syntax, not conditional

Comment: but @SamuelCook really need to have a look on this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_conditional_operator_examples.htm